# how to compare package name from market url in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app which contain broadcast receiver and also contain list of app when user click any particular app he will directed to play store and download that app from jsons response I get all app showing in al list url like "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.launcher" what I have to do is that when app is successfully downloaded in system I will check that app package name of that app from json response url if match then show a toast else error message.
How can I acheive this pls help me Its for a week I am searching.

here is my code for broadcast receiver:-

```
    public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"))
        Log.e("Package Added:-", intent.getData().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try patter matches,see example following link ,i hope help this
http://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String installAppPackgeName = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();     
    String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.launcher";  
    String packageName = getQueryMap(url).get("id");
    if(installAppPackgeName.equals(packageName)){
        // If install app package name is same as url package name then do some task.
        // Your app is installed now.   

    }

}

/** 
 * Get Query String as Key-Value Pair.
 */
public static Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] queryString = query.split("\\?");
    if(queryString.length>1){
        String[] params = queryString[1].split("&");
        for (String param : params) {
            String name = param.split("=")[0];
            String value = param.split("=")[1];
            map.put(name, value);
        }            
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: so i remove this part from broadcast receiver if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"))

Comment: Yes you can. But make sure you register broadcast receiver like.. `<receiver android:name=".receiver.AppInstallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: great friend Thank you so much

Comment: one more this if package name match I have to start Intent service

Comment: How can I do any hint\s

Comment: @Rajesh accept the answer is it help you to resolve your issue.Please check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html for more info about Intent service.

Comment: when I use your that above mentioned code its gives me arror while app closed and any other app is installed

Comment: String[] queryString = query.split("\\?");

Comment: when my app is open I get url from response and compare and when my app is closed and if any app is installed its gives me error becuse it did not get url then how it compare

Comment: @Rajesh you need to store your response in app, either sqlite or shared-preference. And when onReceive method call get persisted data and then compare.

Comment: but this will be harmful for my app beacuse on click buy deal I get deaaction url

Comment: Then may be you can put null check on url.

Comment: I am on my success

Answer (score 0):

extract package name from URL with

```
    String downPack = yourUrl.split("id\\=")[1];
```

extract package name from file

```
public String getPackageNameByAPK(String apkPath, Context context) {
    String packName = "";
    PackageManager packageManager;
    PackageInfo packInfo;

    try {

        if (apkPath == null) return "";

        if (context == null) {
            return "";
        }

        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        packInfo = packageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 0);
        packName = packInfo.packageName;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return packName;
}
```

compare like

```
boolean matched = downPack.equals(getPackageNameByAPK(apkPath,context));
```

This may help you..

Comment: I have to get package name from url  and check with downloaded app packge name only .how can I do boss plss